# Xamarin Forms SwipeGesture Recognizer not working in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, swipe-gesture

I was wondering if someone could help me with this issue that I am currently facing with Xamarin Android where the swipe gesture recognizer does not work. It works fine in Xamarin iOS.

```
               <ads:AdControlView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="adView" Size="MediumRectangle" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="False">
                <ads:AdControlView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped" Direction="Right"/>
                </ads:AdControlView.GestureRecognizers>
            </ads:AdControlView>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that behaviour too. Swipe works only with UWP and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its parent content is visible. As you provided "IsVisible="False" when set to false it disappears from the screen.

Comment: I set it to true in the code behind after the last image of carousel view is swiped right. Then an ad appears, which when swiped right should go back to the carousel view but it doesn't trigger. Thanks.